# Model property initialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I have this model class "UserProfile", it's the original UserProfile class of Membership with a few added properties and methods.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{

   public UserProfile()
   {
       this.DictionaryFrom = "eng";
       this.DictionaryTo = "hun";
       this.trainingType = "normal";
   }


    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string DictionaryFrom { get; set; }
    public string DictionaryTo { get; set; }
    public string trainingType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ForeignExpression> learnedexpressions { get ; set ; }
}
```

My problem is that upon registering a new user, the three fields in the constructor don't get the values assigned to them (so, there's a NULL in the database for each of them).
The user can set them by choosing values from a list, but I'd like to have a default value for all of them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you accidentally unsetting the values elsewhere before saving?

Comment: @ohiodoug I don't think so, it seems that the code in the constructor runs during the creation of the new user, but without any effect on the database.

Comment: Are you including those fields in your form and letting users post them unfilled?

Comment: @dombenoit No, I'm using the default membership registration page (/Account/Register) without any modification

Comment: Can you show your view and controller GET/POST methods as well?

Comment: I would guess that the model isn't being tracked by the context and therefore not seeing that the properties have changed so it isn't inserting the values.

Comment: @ohiodoug Seems likely, but where should I fix this?

Comment: At OSU/Michigan party so I'll answer better after. Look at where you are attaching your model to your DbContext. Try setting the properties after attaching and see if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not being a C# aficionado, I'd do something like this... there's probably a "better" way of doing it.

```
private string myValue = "default value";

public string MyValue {
    get { return myValue; }
    set {
        if (null != value) { myValue = value; }
    }
}
```